# Python two dicts and fetch matching values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary

Have two dicts

```
dictss =[
  {
  'country': 'USA'},

  {'name': 'matt',
  'country': 'USA'},


  {'name': 'tom',
  'country': 'USA'}]
```

and

```
  dicts_to_be_mapped = [{

  'name':'matt'
  }]
```

Trying to map using this :

`res = [d for d in dictss if d["name"] == dicts_to_be_mapped[0]['name']]`

For dicts which doesnt have `name` it is throwing error.  What is the effient way to map two dicts without using pandas and loops. is there a look up function we can use or any find function ?

Comment: You’ve given a working example. What do the dicts that don’t work look like or more precisely a larger example of your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
res = [d for d in dictss if d.get("name") == dicts_to_be_mapped[0]['name']]
print(res)
```

Output

```
[{'name': 'matt', 'country': 'USA'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `d.get` instead of `d["name"]`:

```
res = [d for d in dictss if d.get("name") == dicts_to_be_mapped[0]['name']]
```

The result is:

```
[{'name': 'matt', 'country': 'USA'}]
```